# Storyboard does not return value to original state in WPF DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This XAML code:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowMore}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" >
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"></QuinticEase>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" >
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"></QuinticEase>
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

does not return **Height** back to original value when **ShowMore** becomes False again.

I thought that not setting **To** value in ExitActions will revert value back to original state. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does `ShowMore` correctly fire `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: Do you have any other animations active on the target object (especially on the `Height` property)? Perhaps started by other triggers?